# Need Apple Style Pagination - CSS + HTML only not any jquery

Tags: html, css, pagination

I have created Pagination for my web page but now looking to give it nice look like Apple. I'm not that much expert in CSS.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="my pagination">
    <span class="previous_page">← Previous</span>
    <em class="current">1</em>
    <a rel="next" href="">2</a>
    <a href="">3</a>
    <a href="">4</a>
    <a href="">5</a>
    <a href="">6</a>
    <a href="">7</a>
    <a href="">8</a>
    <a href="">9</a>
    <a href="">10</a>
    <a class="next_page"  href="">Next →</a>
</div>
```

**which looks like :**

← Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Next →

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code design and writing service. You need to show some effort into doing the work yourself before you can expect any assistance from us. As it stands your question is likely to be voted down and closed as not showing enough research on your part.

Answer (score 0):

I have already done it before.

Here is it's CSS

```
.apple_pagination {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: default; }
  .apple_pagination a, .apple_pagination span {
    padding: 0.2em 0.3em; }
  .apple_pagination .disabled {
    color: #aaaaaa; }
  .apple_pagination .current {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #bebebe;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.4em;
    height: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 1px 1px 1px; }
  .apple_pagination a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black; }
    .apple_pagination a:hover, .apple_pagination a:focus {
      text-decoration: underline; }
```

**[JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/GaganGami/Cz3RL/)**